# get parameter from url rewrite

Tags: url-rewriting

I have a problem :
Example : `http://domain/hotel` 
Now I set value: `http://domain/hotel/?tour=hawaii`

How i can get value of variable "tour".

Answer (score 1):

Its all depend how you have extended your url.
The easiest way is by

```
$_GET['tour'];
```

and other way is by wp_query

```
global $wp_query;
$wp_query->query['tour];
```

I think this should help you out.

Comment: sorry, I'm try but it not work. :(

Answer (score 1):

1) $_GET

You could use something like:

```
if (isset($_GET['tour']) && !empty($_GET['tour'])) 
{
    $your_var = $_GET['tour'];
}
```

Now the variable `$your_var` is set with "hawaii" when you load the page `http://domain/hotel/?tour=hawaii`

2) Wordpress Filter

You can also use filter with wordpress.

Here is an other solution : http://www.webopius.com/content/137/using-custom-url-parameters-in-wordpress

Comment: Thank you. Method 2 work fine in my home page of theme. But when i create blank php page. It not work.